# Matplotlib Error Bars

Tags: python, matplotlib

If I run this code:

```
plt.scatter(n, y, marker ='^', s = 30, color = 'k')
plt.errorbar(n, y, yerr=yerror)
plt.ylim(ymin = 5, ymax = 20)
```

The resulting graph has a red line between the scatterplot. How do I prevent this line from appearing? Additionally, how might I add caps to the error bars?

I have tried

```
(_, caps, _) = plt.errorbar(n,y, yerr=yerror, capsize=5, elinewidth=3)

for cap in caps:
    cap.set_color('k')
    cap.set_markeredgewidth(3)
```

and

```
plt.errorbar(n, y, yerr = yerror, ecolor = 'k', capsize = 5)
```

But neither has worked. There is clearly something fundamental I am missing about errorbars.

[image]

Comment: The rest of your styling is not standard mpl, are you importing seaborn or using `mpl.style`?  http://matplotlib.org/api/axes_api.html#matplotlib.axes.Axes.errorbar is a good reference.  Please answer your own question.

Answer (score 1):

After further searching (almost immediately after I posted the question) I have found that adding

```
ls = 'none'
```

within

```
plt.errorbar(n, y, yerr=yerror, ls = 'none')
```

will solve the issue.